# Player class card game

Tags: c#, class, playing-cards

I am working on a card game made of 32 cards. The cards values are 10(highest),9,8,7,king,queen, jack(lowest). Its a card game of four players. there must be five classes including players and tournament. The first class I made was card class:

```
public class Cards
{
    private string face;
    private string suit;

    public Cards(string cardFace, string cardSuit)
    {
        face = cardFace;
        suit = cardSuit;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return face + " van " + suit;
    }
}
```

Then I have defined those cards inside another class which I called it Deck, but what so ever there are no values attached to the cards, inside the deck class there is also the shuffling activity, which should happen after every round

```
public class Deck
{
    private Cards[] deck;
    private int currentCard;
    private const int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 32;
    private Random ranNum;

    public Deck()
    {
        string[] faces = { "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace", "seven", "eight", "Nine", "Ten" };
        string[] suits = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs" };
        deck = new Cards[NUMBER_OF_CARDS];
        currentCard = 0; 
        ranNum = new Random();
        for (int count = 0; count < deck.Length; count++) 
            deck[count] = new Cards(faces[count % 8], suits[count / 8]);
    }

    public void shuffel()
    {
        int currentCard = 0;
        for (int first = 0; first < deck.Length; first++)
        {
            int second = ranNum.Next(NUMBER_OF_CARDS);
            Cards temp = deck[first];
            deck[first] = deck[second];
            deck[second] = temp;

        }
    }

    public Cards DealCards()
    {
        if (currentCard < deck.Length)
            return deck[currentCard++];
        else
            return null;
    }    
}
```

and here is the program class:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Deck deck1 = new Deck();
        deck1.shuffel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(deck1.DealCards());
            if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I am having troubles how to make it as user input the players name which are 4, the dealt cards should go as each player will have four cards , I could make with this code four hands of cards but not assigned to a player's name, as well there should be a user input for which card the user wants to play. Any valuable help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: Could you create Player Class with string name attribute and Deck cards , and add for eachone a deck ?    if ((i + 
 1) % 4 == 0)   player.Add(deck);

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is. You'll need either a `Hand` class that holds the player's identity, or a `Player` class that holds the dealt hand of cards. Pick one.

Comment: yes i am trying to make a player class, and define four players there while the user can input those four players ID